# Wait for another event in WaitHandlesList

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I have 2 events in my WaitHandlesList:

```
this.EventForSit = new AutoResetEvent(false);
this.EventForEat = new AutoResetEvent(false);
this.WaitHandlesList = new WaitHandle[2];
this.WaitHandlesList[0] = this.EventForSit ;
this.WaitHandlesList[1] = this.EventForEat ;
```

I have a method that does some calculations based on event received:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
/*some calculation*/
this.WaitHandlesList.ForEach(theItem =>
            {
                var aEvent = (AutoResetEvent)theItem;
                aEvent.Reset();
            });
 WaitHandle.WaitAny(this.WaitHandlesList);
/*some calculation where a List is being read*/
}
```

I am calling "SomeMethod()" twice simultaneously at different places and first time "EventForSit" is triggered and execution starts. But in between when im waiting for "EventForEat", another thread comes and triggers  "EventForSit" again because of which waiting stops and my code tries to read a list value which is not at all set at that time(The list is set by another thread which triggers "EventForEat").

I want to start execution on "EventForSit" and wait for "EventForEat" and then only process the second "EventForSit" sequentially.
How can i achieve this? Because of thread continuing execution, i get System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

Comment: I have the feeling you are using the wrong tool. What are you trying to do with this? From what I read here, I think you'd be better off with one or two [BlockingCollection<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=net-5.0).

Comment: @Fildor The main concern is i have to process the events in sequence. If that is achieved then blocking collection need not come in picture. First i process "Sit" then wait for "Eat". But since im calling the method again "Sit" sets the waitHandler and execution continues.

Comment: Exactly. That's why you need to think about some different way to do this. For example: You can `Take()` from the BlockingCollection, which blocks until an element gets available. And instead of triggering events, you add to that collection. So by definition, you will handle anything you take in sequence. Now if you have two of those, you can use one for sit and one for eat and take from them alternatingly. This will decouple the sequence of handling from the sequence of event occurrance.

Comment: Please do not double post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69615861/982149